# How to solve this coupled PDEs with integration?

Tags: python, matlab, physics, numerical-methods, pde

I'm solving a system of two coupled partial integro-differential equations as follow,

[image]

in which f(R), V(r,R) and v(r,r') are known functions,  epsilon^alpha and epsilon^beta are unknown, so it is also an eigenvalue problem. The bounary conditions are known as phi^{alpha}(a,R), phi^{alpha}(b,R), phi^{alpha}(r,A) and phi^{alpha}(r,B) which can be express as four arrays, and phi^{beta} is the same(a, b, A, B are four constants of r and R respectively.)

I have tried to use method of lines and discretized the R dimension to transfer the PDEs to ODEs, but I found this method seems not work because MOL requires that the PDE problem is well-posed as an initial value problem in at least one dimension.

Since the PDE seems a little complicated, I have no idea about how to solve it numerically. Any hints will be helpful. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, with a little rearrangement it looks like a Poisson equation for vector variable (phi_alpha, phi_beta). So ... Gauss-Seidel, Jacobi, line Gauss-Seidel, etc.

Comment: @lastchange Thank you for your advice but could you please tell me how to deal with the integration term and the unknown epsilon?

Comment: The integration term can be included by numerical integration as part of an iterative solution. Sorry, I hadn’t noticed that the epsilons were unknowns - are they really functions of R?

Comment: yep, epsilons are functions of R.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what king of help you're asking. You say you want to solve this "numerically", but do you have numerical values for the functions involved?

Comment: ...aaaaaaand the question has been closed :(. Perhaps there is another stackexchange site where it would be more welcome, I don't know. Perhaps https://scicomp.stackexchange.com ? But I encourage you to make it more explicit if you have numerical values for `f(R), V(r,R) and v(r,r')` and whatever other data you have.